# Função findByID do Mongoose não retorna o registro, com NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Tenho uma função do meu controller que não esta funcionando. Ao mandar localizar um registro pelo seu ID ele fica infinitamente tentando resgatar e não consegue e não apresenta nenhum erro no console.

**O controller de busca por ID:**

```js
    //Buscar por ID

exports.getByIDClient = async (req, res, next) => {
  //Extrair o dado da requisição, pela url = req.params

  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const client = await Client.findById({ _id: id }).exec();

    if (!client) {
      res.status(422).json({ message: "O cliente não foi encontrado" });

      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
};
```

**O meu Model do Cliente:**

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    tel: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    number: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Client = mongoose.model("client", clientSchema);

clientSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY, {
    expiresIn: "2d",
  });
  return token;
};


module.exports = { Client };
```

**O meu Router do Cliente:**

```js
    const router = require("express").Router();
const { Client } = require("../models/Client");
//const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const clientController = require("../controllers/Client");

router.get("/", clientController.getAllClients);

router.get("/:id", clientController.getByIDClient);

router.post("/", clientController.postClient);

router.put("/:id", clientController.putClient);

router.delete("/:id", clientController.deleteClient);


module.exports = router;
```

**O meu index.js**

```js
    require("dotenv").config();
const connection = require("./db");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/Users");
const clientRoutes = require("./routes/Client");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/Auth");
const serviceRoutes = require("./routes/Services");
const categoryRoutes = require("./routes/Categories");
const partRoutes = require("./routes/Parts");

const cors = require("cors");

// database connection
connection();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//Middlewares

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/clients", clientRoutes);
app.use("/services", serviceRoutes);
app.use("/categories", categoryRoutes);
app.use("/parts", partRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Busquei na documentação do Mongoose, pelo findById() e findOne() mas não consegui.

Vi também, que alguns formatam a saída do Json "_id": { "$oid": "5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e" } ...mas eu não sei fazer isso ...

Answer (score -2):

Consegui descobrir o problema. Estava no meu controller mesmo. Com a correção ficou assim:

```
    //Buscar por ID
exports.getByIDClient = async (req, res, next) => {
  //Extrair o dado da requisição, pela url = req.params
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const client = await Client.findById({ _id: id }).then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json({ client: result });
    });

    if (!client) {
      res.status(422).json({ message: "O cliente não foi encontrado" });

      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
};
```